# display groupe filed from database using function php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I want to display the specific data from database specific categorie 85,
line  from database :

```
(18769, 3780, 'customdata_group', 'a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:9:\"TitleItem\";s:10:\"abdelkader\";s:16:\"TitleDescription\";s:13:\"  abdelkader2\";}i:1;a:2:{s:9:\"TitleItem\";s:12:\"abdelkaderft\";s:16:\"TitleDescription\";s:11:\"abdelkader3\";}}');
```

Comment: `where categorie = 85` ???

Comment: categorie article